# when I use image made of the Illustrator program for using in main activity, I receive errors

Tags: android

when I use image made of the Illustrator program for using in main activity, I receive errors. I created an image in  Illustrator program and I saved it as "save for web".

But when I put the image in the following code for viewing in main activity, I receive errors. Next, I understood android devices do not support images made of the Illustrator program. What should I do?

activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/info"  >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What kind of errors?

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator as a design tool provides options for saving an image in multiple formats, many of which should be supported by the Android platform.

Illustrator is often a top choice for design, as it allows for scale-able vectors; it is also a feature rich application, providing the designer with flexibility.

You can find the supported media formats for Android here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

I recommend saving the image as a .ai file (illustrator) and importing into Photoshop. Once there, save as a .png or .gif and choose from the additional compression and quality settings.

Another option is to use the "save for web" as you currently are; in the preset options, change the type to JPEG  rather than PNG-8 or PNG-24. GIF may work as well. Here is a more thorough explanation of the differences between the two formats:
http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/png-gif

Edit: Changed to reflect JPEG as the correct media format.

Comment: Thank you.I did all stages step by step.I saved  the image as ai.file and then I opened it  in Photoshop and I saved the image as PNG-24 by "save for web". But the problem is not solved.

Comment: What happens if you try setting the width/height to ="fill_parent", add android:orientation="vertical" right above "android:background", and move "tools:context" below "android:background"? If you can, please post the full error you receive.

Comment: I typed the file name wrong and the errors was for this reason! I typed the file name correctly and now I can run it. but there is a problem.I see a black screen in main activity and not the image.my activity-main is as above code.

Comment: It could be that the location of the file is incorrect and the black screen is a placeholder when it cannot find the image. Are you storing the image in your drawings folder?

Comment: It is correct.I have two image in drawable folder.One normal and the other is my main image that I want put it in main activity.I can see the normal image in main activity but I can not see the my main image in main activity.

Comment: in fact, I used the normal image to ensure the proper functioning of the program

Comment: I found the solution.If we use JPEG, android studio displays the image successfully.But android studio does not support PNG-24.

Comment: Nice! Happy to hear you resolved it. You should post it as an answer to this question and mark it as the correct response, in case anyone else comes across a similar situation.